# Is it possible to install windows in android tablets?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, windows, emulators

I want to have Windows in Android, Is it possible to install windows in android tablets?

Comment: Not natively, until the vendor of tablet and Microsoft are not in line. You can run some kind of emulator though. [IS IT POSSIBLE TO INSTALL WINDOWS, iOS OR LINUX ON ANDROID DEVICE?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-to-instal-windows-ios-linux-t3763961)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](https://www.androidauthority.com/install-windows-on-android-868800/) explains how to install Windows on an Android tablet. **But as it stresses, the app and methods are unsupported, so if something happens to your device, then you are on your own.**

From the article, here are the steps:

> First, you first must install the [Change My Software](http://www.mediafire.com/file/l29a5xd5i1vzaxa/CHANGE+MY+SOFTWARE+ALL.zip) application on your Windows-based PC. There are several versions of the app, each for a different version of the OS (Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10).

After installing the software mentioned above:

> 1. Make sure your Windows PC has a high-speed internet connection.
> 2. Connect your Android tablet to your Windows PC, via a USB cable
> 3. Open the version of the Change My Software tool you want to use.
> 4. Select the Android option in Change My Software, followed by your desired language
> 5. The Change My Software app should then start downloading the required drivers from your Windows PC to your Android tablet.
> 6. Once that’s done, click “Install” to begin the process. Obviously, you should keep your tablet connected to your Windows PC for this entire time. If you want to dual boot between Windows and Android on your tablet when the process is finished, you should not check the “Remove Android” box in the Change My Software app.
> 7. Once Windows has been installed on your Android device, it should either boot directly to the Windows OS, or to the “Choose and operating system” screen if you decided to make the tablet into a dual boot device. After that, your version of Windows should then begin its own normal setup process.